# How to call multi variable array in JS function?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm using this function to select one item in drop down menu:

```js
async selectNode(nodeType, nodeName) {
    await page.click(this.selectors.reset);
    await this.toggleNode(nodeType, nodeName, true);
    await this.select();
  }
```

Now I want to select multi item before  “`await this.select();`” this step.

I tried to edit function like this:

```js
async selectMultiNodes([nodeType, nodeName],) {
    await page.click(this.selectors.reset);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeType.length; i++) {
      await this.toggleNode(nodeType, nodeName, true);
    }
    await this.select();}
```

but when I call this function to select multi item

```
await topologyBrowser.selectMultiNodes(['SGSN-MME', 'mme088'],['EPG', 'epg84-real'],['SAPC', 'sapc17']);
```

it has error

> Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 3

How do I fix this?

Comment: The function takes just one argument *single* list containing 2 items structured into 2 variables (`nodeType` and `nodeName`). Yet you are supplying 3 seperate arguments, the first is `['SGSN-MME', 'mme088']`, the second is `['EPG', 'epg84-real']` and the third is `['SAPC', 'sapc17']`. Did you intend to pass a single argument that is a list? Even then the syntax of the function would be incorrect, since you couldn't de-structure like that.

Comment: try like that `[['SGSN-MME', 'mme088'],['EPG', 'epg84-real'],['SAPC', 'sapc17']].forEach(function(e) { return this.selectmUltinOdes(arr); } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a method take an arbitrary number of arguments using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`

```js
function tryMe(...args){
  console.log(args);
}

tryMe(1,2,3);
```

So you could make your method take an arbitrary number of arrays and deconstruct them in a loop

```js
async function selectMultiNodes(...nodes) {
   for(let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
     const [nodeType,nodeName] = nodes[i];
     console.log(nodeType,nodeName);
   }
}
selectMultiNodes(['SGSN-MME', 'mme088'],['EPG', 'epg84-real'],['SAPC', 'sapc17']);
```

So your final code would be

```
async selectMultiNodes(...nodes) {
    await page.click(this.selectors.reset);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      const [nodeType,nodeName] = nodes[i];
      await this.toggleNode(nodeType, nodeName, true);
    }
    await this.select();
}
```